# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=2}^{k}(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}\frac{1}{\ln n}$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Please help me to check convergence of $$\sum_{n=2}^{k}(-1)^{[\sqrt n]}\frac{1}{\ln n}$$

I think it diverges, because it don't absolute converge, and it won't stabilze at large $n$, but how to prove it?

Comment: Jonny, $[\sqrt{n}]=\mbox{ integer part of } \sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: If true, the remark that *it won't stabil(i)ze at large n* is an extremely good one, but how would you prove it?

Comment: What about [Leibniz](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeibnizCriterion.html) Criterion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let  $S_k$ note the sum from 2 to k. Then for $ k \geq 2 $ we have

$$ |S_{ (k+1)^2 - 1 } - S_{ k^2 - 1 }| = | \sum_{j=k^2}^{(k+1)^2 - 1} (-1)^{\lfloor \sqrt{j} \rfloor} \dfrac{1}{\ln j}| = |(-1)^k| |\sum_{j = k^2 }^{ (k+1)^2 - 1}  \dfrac{1}{\ln j}| \geq  (2k - 1 ) \times \dfrac{1}{\ln (k+1)^2} = \dfrac{2k-1}{2\ln (k + 1)}, $$ which does not converge to 0 as $ k \to \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $s_k$ be the $k$-th partial sum of our series. We show that the sequence $(s_k)$ does not converge, by showing it is not a Cauchy sequence.

Take $M=(2t)^2$ and $N=(2t+1)^2-1$.  For any $n$ between $M$ and $N$, $\lfloor\sqrt{n}\rfloor=2t$, so $\lfloor \sqrt{n}\rfloor$ is even.

Thus $s_N-s_M$ is a sum of positive terms. There are $4t+1$ such terms, each $\gt \frac{1}{\log(2t+1)^2}$. So 
$s_N-s_M \gt \frac{4t+1}{2\log(t+1)}$.

The right side can be made arbitrarily large by taking $t$ suitably large. In particular, the sequence of partial sums is not Cauchy, so does not converge.